# How to make a profile page with editable field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a profile page. The overall design is done but I need to add an edit button which will be use to update some prodfile information.

For now, I would like the page to look the same just have 3 fields which became editable when I click on the Edit button.

The scenario is:

- Page load and by default the page is not editable
- The user click on edit, specific fields became editable, the previously named "Edit" button become "Save" btn.
- When the user finished its update, he click on Save. The fields became not editable and the button is renamed to "Edit"

The UI look like this :

[image]

the related code for the editable part is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import './Profile.css';

import UserProfile from '../assets/fake/studentinfo'
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import Gallery from 'react-grid-gallery';
import DetailReview from '../components/materialdesign/DetailReview';
import {Tabs, Tab, Col, Row}  from 'react-bootstrap';
import EmptyTile from '../components/EmptyTile';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


class Profiles extends React.Component{

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isUserAccount: true, 
            userId: '', 
            userInfo: UserProfile.User1.values,
            editMode: false,
            profileBtnActionName: "Edit"};
    }


    onProfileBtnAction = () => {
        if(false){
            this.setState({profileBtnActionName: "Save"})
            this.setState({editMode: true})
        } else {
            this.setState({profileBtnActionName: "Edit"})
            this.setState({editMode: false})
        }
    }

    updateUserProfileData = () => {
        console.log("test update")
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    /*    let { id } = useParams();
        if((id!==null) && (id !== '')) {
            this.setState({userId: id})
            this.setState({isUserAccount: false})
            this.fetchData(id);
        }*/
    }

    fetchData = id => {
        this.setState({userInfo: UserProfile.User2.values})
    };

    render(){


        return(
            <div className="profile-container">
                <div className="profile-header" 
                    style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.userInfo.profileHeaderImag})`}}>
                        <img 
                        src={this.state.userInfo.profileImg} 
                        alt="profileImg"
                        className="profile-header-image-user"/>                    
                </div>
                <div className="profile-content">
                    <Row>
                    <Col sm={8}>
                        <h1 contenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.name} </h1>
                        <h3 contenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.city}  </h3>
                        <h2> {TextContents.Biography} </h2>
                        <p ccontenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.bio}  </p>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={2}>
                        <Button bsPrefix="btn-edit-profile"
                            onClick={this.onProfileBtnAction}>{this.state.profileBtnActionName}</Button>
                    </Col>
                    </Row>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default Profiles;
```

The editable fields are "Name, location and biography". I think that I am not too far from having it done but I am not quite sure about the logic for `onProfileBtnAction` and how to make sure that the fields are properly updated on the UI and how to extract those updated data to send them later to the BE

Thanks for your help

Comment: where are the form elements for when `this.state.editMode` is `true` ? : https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html once you have form inputs you can add `onChange` handlers that `setState`, You can then pull the updated state variables to pass along to the save handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would really avoid making them contentEditable for editing, you are going to run into issues getting the values unless you assign a ref and dig in. Instead I would replace the tags with inputs when editing. Then you can set those values in your state in order to save them

```
<Col sm={8}>
    {this.state.editMode ?
        <>
            <input />
            <input />
            <h2>{TextContents.Biography}</h2>
            <input />
        </> :
        <>
            <h1 contenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.name} </h1>
            <h3 contenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.city}  </h3>
            <h2> {TextContents.Biography} </h2>
            <p ccontenteditable={this.state.editMode}> {this.state.userInfo.bio}  </p>
        </>
    }
</Col>
```

You are really close with your onProfileButtonAction. You want something like

```
    onProfileBtnAction = () => {
        if(this.state.editMode){
            // Get your values and save here

            // Reset back to read only state
            this.setState({profileBtnActionName: "Edit", editMode: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({profileBtnActionName: "Save", editMode: true});
        }
    }
```